# Format duration string to h m d

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I want to write a function which takes as a parameter string in the format of hh:mm (26:40) for example.

I need the function to return as output the string "1 d, 2 h, 40 min"

I've tried to search for a built-in function or best practice without luck.

I've come up with the following code and it's working, but I feel it's overkill and I would like to know whether there is a best practice for it.

```js
var t = "27:20"
var res = foo(t)
document.writeln(res);

function foo(st) {
  var splittedSt = st.split(":")
  var days = parseInt(splittedSt[0] / 24, 10) + " d";
  var hours = Number(splittedSt[0]) - Number(days.split(" ")[0]) * 24 + " h";
  var minutes = splittedSt[1] + " min";
  return days + " " + hours + " " + minutes
}
```

Comment: Using moment or date.js to handle such a trivial task for which you have 5 lines of code would be the ultimate overkill

Comment: @mplungjan would you mind show us all how to solve this trivial task? Most date representations seems to follow the convention that a day consists of no more than 24 hours. Thus you would need to manipulate the input any way.

Comment: It is solved in OP's question. He wants code that is NOT overkill and I explained that adding a framework or such to make the 5 lines he has now work in a more elegant way IS the actual overkill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it with momentjs lib as mplungjan suggested in his comment (already had usage with moment inside the project).

one simple line with the relevant format.

```
console.log(moment.duration("27:20").format("d [d], h [h], m [min]"));
```

would give the result:

```
1 d, 3 h, 20 min
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this

```js
var t = "27:20"
var res = foo(t)
document.writeln(res);
function foo(st){
    var splittedSt = st.split(":")
    var days = parseInt(splittedSt[0] / 24) + " d";
    var hours = parseInt(splittedSt[0] % 24) + " h";
    var minutes = splittedSt[1] + " min";
    return days + " " + hours + " " + minutes
}
```

Comment: What did you improve except remove some unnecessary Number?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. Generally the task that you are trying to solve can be broken down into two steps.

1. Calculate the total number og base unites in the input (here minuts)
2. Convert this number to the desired format.

The following code splits the input into years, days, hours, and minutes:

```js
document.writeln("27:20 -> " + foo("27:20:0"));
document.writeln("8760:0 -> " + foo("8760:0"));
document.writeln("-8760:0 -> " + foo("-8760:0"));

function foo(st) {
  var splittedSt = st.split(":")
  // STEP 1
  var total = parseInt(splittedSt[0]) * 60 + parseInt(splittedSt[1]);
 
  // STEP 2
  var minutes = parseInt(total % 60);
  var hours = parseInt(total / 60) % 24;    
  var days = parseInt(total / 60 / 24) % 365;
  var years = parseInt(total / 60 / 24 / 365) ; 
  
  return years + " years " + days + " days " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes"
}
```

Although this might seem like a loot of code for at relatively simple problem, there is really no other way to do it. However most programming languages has built-in functions for handle many simple problems as this. Unfortunately my experience in Javascript is very limited. Hence, I am not able to achieve this, but @mplungjan might have some input on this?

Comment: Where is the improvement?

Answer (score 0):

```
 foo=s=>(((h,m)=>(Math.floor(h/24)+"d "+(h%24)+"h "+m+"m") )(...s.split(":")) );
```

thats quite short i think

http://jsbin.com/xujupimefi/edit?console